# Dropdown Loses Focus As Soon As I Try to Select a Value

Tags: c#, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui-autocomplete

So the context is an MVC 4 internet application with razor views.

Here is the input field where I want the autocomplete dropdown to appear:

```
<td>
  <div class="editor-field">
    <input type="text" id="catSelector" />
    @*@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Category, new { id = "catSelector" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Category)*@
  </div>
</td>
```

The script part is the following (placed at the bottom of my page):

```
<script>

$('#catSelector').autocomplete({    source: getCategories,});


function getCategories(request, response) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Activity/GetCategories',
        data: { query: request.term },
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {

            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.Name,
                    value: item.CategoryId
                };
            }));
        }
    });

}
```

The server action ("Activity/GetCategories") is this one :

```
public JsonResult GetCategories(string query = "")
{

  var result= _dal.SelectCategories(query);

  return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

Basically a category is just a name and an id.

So far, I managed to get the ajax call working an returning the json data (checked with firebug, everything is fine for the data part).

When I start typing search criteria, the autocomplete dropdown appears below the input field.

**BUT as soon as I try to navigate throuht the retreived values (either with keyboard or by selecting value with the mouse), the dropdown disapears and the input field loses focus.**

What could be possibly wrong here with my code ?

I must add that I work with Metro UI CSS 2.0 (styles and js) that caused me some trouble some times ago with the jQuery ui datepicker. So I tried to de activate all Metro ui css scripts, but with no luck.

And finaly, this problem appears on both Chrome and Firefox.

Thank you all in advance for your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... I had two jquery ui script referenced in my solution : the one with all in one file AND the individual components files...

My bad...